# Efficiently multiplying vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I have two vectors in the form of columns, e.g.:

```
a = 1
    2
    3
    4
    5

b = 2
    1
    3
    5
    4
```

I am using the following code to retrieve the product of each:

```
for i = 1 : length(a)
    ab(i) = a(i) * b(i);       
end
```

This gives:

```
ab = 2
     2
     9
     20
     20
```

This is fine, and it produces the correct answer, but it seems slightly inefficient; I presume there must be a syntactical way of doing this without the 'for' loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

`a.*b`

notice the `.` before the `*` which tells Matlab to do the multiplication element by element.

Comment: Thanks. Been using MATLAB for nearly a year now and didn't know about this(!)